# Where do I change OpenSSL configurations in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl

I'm not sure if this has to be done in my application, or if it's a global configuration, but I want to do the following:

> While not recommended in general, it is possible to disable peer
>   certificate verification for a request by setting the **verify_peer**
>   context option to FALSE, and to disable peer name validation by
>   setting the verify_peer_name context option to FALSE.

Where is the verify_peer variable located?

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php)

**Reason:** I'm having trouble sending emails (using PHPMailer, but had similar troubles with Pear Mail) to my server over SSL. I have tried my code on several machines, and it works fine on PHP 5.5, but fails on PHP 5.6. I'm trying to find exactly what caused it to stop working on PHP 5.6.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you would want to do this

Comment: It's not a global option; that said, you should set the cafile or capath ini settings so that peer verification works.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Bit confused. I cannot seem to find a file called cafile.ini or capath.ini. Or are you saying I need to set some value in my application? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`verify_peer` is a setting of a stream context that you can create, e.g.:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
  'ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
  ],
]);
```

and then calling the function that uses stream wrappers with that context, e.g.:

```
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
```

Edit:
Assuming you use `$mail->isSMTP();` you'll need to modify the `PHPMailer` class to make it pass that option in the `smtpConnect()` call so:

```
if (!$this->smtpConnect(['ssl'=>['verify_peer' => false]])) {
        throw new phpmailerException($this->lang('smtp_connect_failed'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
}
```

But it would be better to fix your trusted certificates setup as suggested in the comments.